# Recurrence relations for annuities

Tags: recurrence-relations, actuarial-science

I need help figuring out recurrence relations for various annuities. I've attacked the questions below and my responses. I'm not too sure what the recurrence relation is for d) however. I have attached what I have done so far for all the recurrence relation questions. Any help is much appreciated

Questions:

A recurrence relation is an equation that recursively defines a sequence of values, whereby

each element of a sequence can be written as a function of preceding element(s);

the first element of the sequence will be uniquely defined by an initial value of the recurrence relation.

Specifically, if a sequence $u_n$ can be expressed as a function of only n and the immediate preceding element $u_n−1$, i.e., $u_n = g(n, u_n−1)$, then we say that $u_n$ is a recurrence relation of order 1. The values of the entire sequence can be calculated recursively starting from the initial value say $u_1$ and then by $u_2 = g(2, u_1)$ and more generally $u_n = g(n, u_n−1)$ for $n = 3, 4, 5, · · · $

(a) Write down a recurrence relation for $\ddot a_n$ . Explain your thought process in words (e.g.,using the timeline approach) OR prove the result mathematically by first principles. Also write down the initial value for the sequence.

My answer-

Recurrence relation: $\ddot a_ {\bar n|} = \ddot a_{\bar {n-1}|} + v^{n-1}$

$\ddot a_ {\bar1|}=1$

$\ddot a_ {\bar n|}=1+v+v^2+...+v^{n-1}$

$\ddot a_ {\bar 2|} =1+v= \ddot a_1+v$

Therefore the regression is proven

(b) Given an effective discrete periodic rate of 3% per period, tabulate the values of $\ddot a_n$ for $n = 1, 2, · · · , 30.$

(c) Repeat parts (a) and (b) for an instead of $\bar a_n $ .

My recurrence relation: $ \bar a_n = \bar a_{n-1} + \frac {d} {\delta} v^{n-1}$

Initial value: $ \bar a_1 = \frac {d} {\delta}$

$ \bar a_2 = \frac {d} {\delta} + \frac {d} {\delta}  v = \bar a_1 + \frac {d} {\delta}  v$

And so on therefore the regression is proven

(d) Repeat parts (a) and (b) for $(I \ddot a)_n$ instead of $\ddot a_n$ .

[Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRvyS.png)

[Question a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05idA.png)

[Question c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENDhp.png)

[My attempt at d)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYciR.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how to format these questions

Comment: Well, look at the tutorial and do your best.  People will help you if you make an effort.

Comment: I tried my best.

Comment: Sorry, but your proofs don't prove anything. In a), for example, I take it you are given the formula $\ddot a_n=1+v+v^2+\cdots+v^{n-1}$, and you're meant to prove $\ddot a_n=\ddot a_{n-1}+v^{n-1}$, but there's no $\ddot a_{n-1}$ in your proof, so it can't be a proof of what you're meant to prove.

Comment: And since you never say what the $I$ in $(I\ddot a)_n$ stands for, it's hard to say anything about d).

Comment: I'm supposed to write down a recurrence relation for the annuity and then explain why I got that. This is related to mathematical finance where $ \ddot a_n$ is an annuity where payments are made in advance at the beginning of the period

Comment: It's not asking me to prove an equation or anything, its asking me to write a recurrence relation for that annuity, and then explain my thought process

Comment: Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I thought I did help you out. Your answer for a) is not an answer, since writing down a few equations does nothing to explain your thought process. How can your thought process not involve $\ddot a_{n-1}$? Also, you refuse to tell us what $(I\ddot a)_n$ means. And what are all the decorations on your subscripts, the vertical bar after the number or letter, and the horizontal bar over it?

Comment: No I need recurrence relations like heropup answered. Can you help with a recurrence relation for c?

Answer (score 1):

$\ddot a_{\overline{n}\rceil i}$ represents the present value of an annuity-due of $1$ paid at the beginning of each period with periodic effective interest rate $i$, for $n$ periods (payments).  As such, it is easy to see that the present value of the $k^{\rm th}$ payment is $v^{k-1}$, where $v = 1/(1+i)$ is the periodic present value discount factor.  The sum of the present values of each payment is therefore $$\ddot a_{\overline{n}\rceil i} = 1 + v + v^2 + \cdots + v^{n-1}.$$

We may also observe that for such an annuity-due, if there is an additional payment at the beginning of period $n+1$, the present value of this payment is simply $v^n$; therefore, the total present value is the sum of the present values of the annuity-due for the first $n$ periods, plus the present value of the $(n+1)^{\rm th}$ payment; i.e. $$\ddot a_{\overline{n+1}\rceil i} = (1 + v + v^2 + \cdots + v^{n-1}) + v^n = \ddot a_{\overline{n}\rceil i} + v^n.$$  This is one such recursion relation.

Another possible recursion relation that we may write is found by considering that by deferring an annuity-due of $n$ payments by one period, we get the equivalent of the cash flow for payments $2, 3, \ldots, n+1$ on an annuity-due with $n+1$ payments, hence $$\ddot a_{\overline{n+1}\rceil i} = 1 + v(1 + v + v^2 + \cdots + v^{n-1}) = 1 + v \ddot a_{\overline{n}\rceil i}.$$

Part (b) is trivial and is left as an exercise.

Part (c) is unclear.  Is the question asking for the recurrence for $a_{\overline{n}\rceil i}$, an annuity-immediate for $n$ periods, or for $\bar{a}_{\overline{n}\rceil i}$, a **continuous** annuity over $n$ periods with effective periodic interest rate $i$?

Part (d) requires more consideration than you have provided in your work.  We have $$(I\ddot a)_{\overline{n}\rceil i} = 1 + 2v + 3v^2 + \cdots + nv^{n-1}.$$  This is the definition along the lines of what we have reasoned for the level annuity-due above.  We wish to establish a recursion relation for this.  Of course, we can simply write $$(I\ddot a)_{\overline{n+1}\rceil i} = (1 + 2v + 3v^2 + \cdots + nv^{n-1}) + (n+1)v^n = (I \ddot a)_{\overline{n}\rceil i} + (n+1)v^n,$$ or we can write 
$$\begin{align*}
(I \ddot a)_{\overline{n+1}\rceil i} &= 1 + 2v + 3v^2 + \cdots + (n+1)v^n \\
&= (1 + v + v^2 + \cdots + v^n) + (v + 2v^2 + 3v^3 + \cdots + nv^n) \\
&= \ddot a_{\overline{n}\rceil i} + v(1 + 2v + 3v^2 + \cdots + nv^{n-1}) \\
&= \ddot a_{\overline{n}\rceil i} + v (I\ddot a)_{\overline{n}\rceil i}
\end{align*}$$
The problem you are having is that you are not reasoning from first principles, instead electing to use the derived formulas for these annuities, when you have not in fact demonstrated them to be true.  Moreover, these formulas are not particularly useful for writing out recurrence relations, since the original summation much more readily yields a number of possible recurrences.

Comment: For c: $ \bar a_n$ is a continuous annuity with payments made continuously over infinitely small intervals of dt. It calculates the PV at the beginning of the period.
Also, how do I derive it from first principles? I'm not quite sure of that

Comment: And for d), would another way to write the recurrence relation be: $ (I \ddot a)_n = (I \ddot a)_{n-1} + (n+1)v^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: Can you help with c) please?

Comment: @Spartasporter No.  You need to figure it out on your own.  I have already given you the logical framework for how to proceed with the solution based on the other parts of your question.  Continuing to ask in this manner is inappropriate and against site policy.

Comment: Ok. I apologise, it's just that I'm not too sure about writing out the values as it is a continuous annuity and payments aren't made in steps.

Comment: Hi. I've tried having a go at c) and am not sure what to do. I think the recurrence relation has something to do with integrals or something. Could you please help me out? Thanks